# Making next pages via javascript without refreshing or new page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make this script to go new page without refreshing. Should I try it in javascript? Or there's an easier way? I tried to make with next/prev button but i couldn't do it, at least on myself. Here I put the code and I'll show you what i tried

If cannot be done with java, how else can i do, at least to give impression that page is not refreshing / changing.

```
<section id="wrap">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <section class="features">
                                    <div class=page1">
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <h3 class="major">To be Edited</h3>
                                            <p>To be Edited</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="special">Click pentru a viziona.</a>
                                        </article>
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <h3 class="major">To be Edited</h3>
                                            <p>To be Edited</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="special">Click pentru a viziona.</a>
                                        </article>
                                                                            <section class="features">
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <h3 class="major">To be Edited</h3>
                                            <p>To be Edited</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="special">Click pentru a viziona.</a>
                                        </article>
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <h3 class="major">To be Edited</h3>
                                            <p>To be Edited</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="special">Click pentru a viziona.</a>
                                        </article>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class=page2">
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <h3 class="major">To be Edited</h3>
                                            <p>To be Edited</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="special">Click pentru a viziona.</a>
                                        </article>
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <h3 class="major">To be Edited</h3>
                                            <p>To be Edited</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="special">Click pentru a viziona.</a>
                                        </article>
                                                                            <section class="features">
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <h3 class="major">To be Edited</h3>
                                            <p>To be Edited</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="special">Click pentru a viziona.</a>
                                        </article>
                                        <article>
                                            <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                            <h3 class="major">To be Edited</h3>
                                            <p>To be Edited</p>
                                            <a href="#" class="special">Click pentru a viziona.</a>
                                        </article>
                                        </div>
                                                                                <ul class="pagination">
                                            <li><span class="button small disabled">Prev</span></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="page active">1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#2" class="page">2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="page">3</a></li>
                                            <li><span>&hellip;</span></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="page">8</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="page">9</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="page">10</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" class="button small">Next</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </section>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </section>
```

what i tried

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pages = $('#container li'), current=0;
    var currentPage,nextPage;

    $('#container .button').click(function(){
        currentPage= pages.eq(current);
        if($(this).hasClass('prevButton'))
        {

            if (current <= 0)
                current=pages.length-1;
            else
                current=current-1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (current >= pages.length-1)
                current=0;
            else
                current=current+1;
        }
        nextPage = pages.eq(current);   
        pages.hide(); 
        nextPage.show();        
    }).filter('.nextButton').click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: what's the status of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to display new pages without having to load them.
But what you are trying to do is possible.
You just need to add the HTML content and CSS of the page you want in your current DOM. And then with some CSS rules and javascript, animate your DOM.

This can be done dynamically when you click your next button (then you display an activity indicator while it's loading the content of your next page)

Or when you first load your initial page. In that case the HTML of your next page will just be hidden, and you won't have any loading time when pressing "next".

I would recommend the first approach as your code can become really messy in the second case.

In your DOM you would have something like that:

```
<div class="myFirstPageClass">
    your content of your first page
</div>

<div class="mySecondPageClass">
    your second page
</div>
```

And in your js, if you use jQuery it would be something like that when you click on next:

```
$('.myFirstPageClass').hide();
$('.mySecondPageClass').show();
```

But yeah, as BShaps explained, you should definitely use a framework. They will help you structure you code.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it sounds like you're asking how to build a SPA (Single Page Application) with vanilla javascript.  I don't really recommend it because it is a pain so I would suggest using a framework that makes creating a SPA much easier.

But, if you really want to try it with vanilla js then here is a link showing you how to do it: [SPA with vanilla js](https://dev.to/vinay20045/building-a-single-page-application-with-vanilla-js)